# ¿Cómo imprimo los elementos char de un vector en C++?

Tags: c++, array

Pues, este es un vector que intenta capturar las letras, o sea, que cada elemento del vector sea una letra que se va digitando, no obstante, al final no sé cómo imprimir las letras antes digitadas.

Esta es solo una función.

---

```
char ingresaChar()
{
    char character = ' ';
    int i = 0;

    if (i < 100) {
        while (character != '0') {
            cout << "Digite una letra para formar la frase, o digite '0' para finalizar" << endl;
            cout << "Letra: ";
            cin >> frase[i];

            character = frase[i];

            i++;
        }
        cout << "elemento " << i << " es: " << frase[i] << endl;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la misma manera que recogiste letra por letra, muestra letra por letra:

```
// Recoger datos.
while (character != '0') {
    cout << "Digite una letra para formar la frase, o digite '0' para finalizar" << endl;
    cout << "Letra: ";
    cin >> frase[i];

    character = frase[i];

    i++;
}

// Mostrar datos.
for (int indice = 0; indice < i; ++indice)
    cout << frase[indice];
```

Comment: Comprendo, era básicamente un nuevo ciclo con un nuevo iterador. Me ayudaste a aprender más que mis clases. ¡Gracias!

Comment: No, no es un nuevo ciclo con un nuevo iterador. Es un bucle `for` con un indexador (`indice`) que hace ciclos hasta que el indexador tiene el mismo valor que la variable que usaste para indizar los datos al recogerlos (`i`). Los iteradores son otra cosa.

Comment: Eres muy amable. ¡Gracias!... y me disculpo por los errores, soy novato aún. :P